# Javascript onclick shows last element of array with for loop

Tags: javascript

I have little problem. I am working with one companys API's. I request for activities and they return me array of activities. Here is part of code.

```
client.requestActivities(function(activities) {
        if (activities.length > 0) {
            for(i=0; i < activities.length; i++) {
                var activity = activities[i];
                activity.onStart(function() { alert(i+ " started"); });
                activity.onCredit(function() { alert(i+ " credit"); });
                activity.onClose(function() { alert(i+ " close"); });
                activity.onFinish(function() { alert(i+ " finish"); });
                            $('.Game-Screen-Footer').append('<div class="Game-Screen-Footer-Adv" id="foota'+i+'"><a href="javascript:;" ><img src="'+activity.image_url+'" alt="'+activity.display_text+'" width="190" height="110"></a></div>');
                document.getElementById('foota'+i+'').onclick = function() {
                ARNO.box.show({html:'<div id="socialVibeFancyBox0"></div>', close: false, width:activity.window_width, height:activity.window_height, openjs: 
                            function(){
                                client.loadActivityIntoContainer(activity, 'socialVibeFancyBox0');
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
```

}

Mostly, this function give back array with 3 elements. But when I click on first activity, onStart it should alert me (0 start), but it alerts (4 start), this means, that it alerts last element of i. How should I fix this? I tried a lot of stuff, but I haven't find solution, maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 5):

This is yet another case of closure problems. Try this:

```
for( i=0; i<activities.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        // your code here
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: @Kolnik: That sounds interesting. Do you have to a reference Q&A which explains this *closure problems* in detail at hand?

Answer (score 0):

Move the guts of the `for` loop out to a function, and pass in the values that need to be scoped separately.

```
for(i=0; i < activities.length; i++) {
    setUpActivity(i, activities[i]);
}
```

---

```
function setUpActivity(i, activity) {

    activity.onStart(function() { alert(i+ " started"); });
    activity.onCredit(function() { alert(i+ " credit"); });
    activity.onClose(function() { alert(i+ " close"); });
    activity.onFinish(function() { alert(i+ " finish"); });
    ARNO.box.show({
        html:'<div id="socialVibeFancyBox0"></div>', 
        close: false, width:activity.window_width, 
        height:activity.window_height, 
        openjs:function(){
                    client.loadActivityIntoContainer(activity, 'socialVibeFancyBox0');
                }
            });
}
```

A function invocation creates a new variable scope. any variables or parameters created in the function will be in their own scope, and the functions created in the same scope will have permanent reference to those variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about IE8- then ES5 already solves this issue with `forEach`:

```
activities.forEach(function(v, i){
  // now 'i' will work anywhere within this scope
});
```