# Add onlick event listener in look doesnt work js

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dom-events

This is how my item `html` looks like:

```
<div class="content__products__item" id="item1">
   <div class="content__products__item__picture">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/product-tea1.jpg"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="content__products__item__section">green tea</div>
   <div><a href="#" class="content__products__item__name">Loan si</a></div>
   <div class="content__products__item__price">
      <span>3.45</span> r
   </div>
   <div class="content__products__item__quantity clearfix">
      <button class="quantity-arrow-minus">-</button>
      <div class="quantity-num"><span>50</span> г</div>
      <button class="quantity-arrow-plus">+</button>
      <button class="quantity-add-to-basket">В корзину</button>
   </div>
   <div class="content__products__item__description-wraper">
      <div class="content__products__item__description">
         Good tea Good teaGood teaGood teaGood tea
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I add `id` on each item in my html markup and then I javascript I take all my items and trying to add onclick event on each of my items but idk why when I clock on each of my plus minus buttons on any item it changes only the last item's value .

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.content__products__item');

for (var i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
    var btnMinus = document.querySelector('#item' + i + ' .quantity-arrow-minus');
    var btnPlus = document.querySelector('#item' + i + ' .quantity-arrow-plus');
    var input = document.querySelector('#item' + i + ' .quantity-num span');
    var currentPrice = document.querySelector('#item' + i + ' .content__products__item__price span');
    var pricePerGram = currentPrice.textContent / 50;
    btnPlus.onclick = function (e) {
        input.textContent = +input.textContent + 50;
        currentPrice.textContent = (+input.textContent * pricePerGram).toFixed(2);
    }
    btnMinus.onclick = function (e) {
        if (input.textContent > 50) {
            input.textContent = +input.textContent - 50;
            currentPrice.textContent = (+input.textContent * pricePerGram).toFixed(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Well you use global variables, that would be the start of your problem. Use `var`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript onclick shows last element of array with for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718284/javascript-onclick-shows-last-element-of-array-with-for-loop)

Comment: `items.length` equals 1. So your you never enter the body of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did it this way:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.content__products__item');

  items.forEach(function(item, i) {
    var btnMinus = document.querySelector('#item' + n + ' .quantity-arrow-minus');
    var btnPlus = document.querySelector('#item' + n + ' .quantity-arrow-plus');
    var input = document.querySelector('#item' + n + ' .quantity-num span');
    var currentPrice = document.querySelector('#item' + n + ' .content__products__item__price span');
    var pricePerGram = currentPrice.textContent / 50;
    btnPlus.onclick = function(e) {
      input.textContent = +input.textContent + 50;
      currentPrice.textContent = (+input.textContent * pricePerGram).toFixed(2);
    }
     btnMinus.onclick = function(e) {
       if(input.textContent > 50) {
       input.textContent = +input.textContent - 50;
      currentPrice.textContent = (+input.textContent * pricePerGram).toFixed(2);
       }
    }
  });
```

Now it works good!